# How to change year range in jquery DateTimePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker

I am using jquery `DateTimePicker` plugin and I have to change year range form 2008 to 2018.I am using [this plugin](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#defaultDate), Please help me in this.

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
 timepicker:false,
 format:'d-m-Y',
 changeMonth: true, 
 changeYear: true, 
yearRange: '2008:2018'
});
```

Comment: You should use datepicker only because you already false the timepicker.

Comment: Thank you for replying Mr.Mohit, I am using this plugin http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#defaultDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d-m-Y',
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true, 
    yearStart : '2008',
    yearEnd :'2018'
});
```

Comment: Mr.Mohit, Is there any way If user manually typed date 2007 then he will get error?

Comment: Use this code to not allowing user to write anything in text-box.

$("#datetimepicker").keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});

Answer (score 0):

You can try yearEnd: 2018,yearStart: 2008.

Comment: Hybreeder see my answer i posted it first. Please mark it as answer

Comment: Mr.Abhishek, One more help from your side, Is there any way If user manually typed date 2007 then he will get error?

Comment: Other dates except of range 2008-2018 will be disabled and u can try and you can have date validity checked in backend.

Comment: Right but user can type manually like 1/1/2007 and its accepting that i don't want...Any idea ?please help me in this